# How to wait for controller is rendered in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a custom jquery plugin which transforms table to a tree. And when i'm loading data from ng model i need to recall plugin's constructor. but i can not find that event, when i need to call that.
I've tried to $watch model variable - doen't work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new `directive` instead of doing this in a controller.

By using a directive, you'll be sure that the code located in its `link` function is applyed after DOM complilation.

It is intended to do what you want.

see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive